Is there a way to parse terminal code escapes to formated string in javascript?
My problem is basically the following: I need a set of characters and terminal commands to replicate the result of the text in the terminal. For example, the following string:
"\bt\be\bs\bt\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[1@1\u001b[1@2\u001b[1@3\b\b\b\u001b[1P" 

should print 23test in the terminal.
To explain better what I’m doing: I’m taking the stdin of what I’m typing and putting it into an array, then I join it to create a string. When I print this string with console.log(), the string is formatted correctly. However, when I put this string into a file or pass it into an object like {test: string} and print this object, the string appears in the format shown earlier. This makes me think that the terminal can understand this type of string format. I would like to know if there is any parser for this or if I should create a function to handle these character sequences.
I have already tried creating a function, but it seemed to become more complex than necessary. I can’t even find a more technical name to start my research. I am using Node.js.

I don't know if there's an equivalent in JS, but you could shell out to the col -b command.

I'm not a node.js developer, but if I'm not mistaken I believe this might be in the ballpark: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-parser
